# Firebase: Accessing Data Stored via childByAutoID

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So my Firebase data structure looks like this:

[My JSON data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPYWA.png)

My question is simple. How do I access the ID's that have been stored via the childByAutoID method i.e. what is the key to their value. The reason I want to do this is because I want to create a variable that will hold the ID, and this only (the value generated by childByAutoId), for example, if you look at My JSON data structure image, KMVrGnR76E6vrj61K21 will be stored in the variable and this alone. My current query looks like this:

```
databaseRef.child("Jokes").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in

            let jokeId = snapshot.//something??? not .key as this returns Jokes


        })
```

I understand that the childByAutoId generates a unique identifier, but surely there must be a way to retrieve and store that identifier (this alone, not all of it's children) for obvious reasons...

Comment: please let others know my answer worked by accepting it if it did :)

Comment: @rigdonmr thanks for trying to help, unfortunately this didnt work as the key is Jokes. Therefore my array returns [Jokes, Jokes, Jokes], not the autoId.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the answer. To access the key of the randomly generated autoId, you have to pass it as a FIRDataSnapShot.

```
for snap in snapshot.children.allObjects {

            let id = snap as! FIRDataSnapshot

            print(id.key)

        }
```

This will give you the randomly generated keys.

Answer (score 2):

`snapshot.key` should get you the id for each joke in this case

Comment: thanks for trying to help, unfortunately this didnt work as the key is Jokes. Therefore my array returns [Jokes, Jokes, Jokes], not the autoId.

Answer (score 0):

Within the for block, `joke.key` will be the id of the current child.

See [FIRDataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/interface_f_i_r_data_snapshot)

Comment: I have changed my question as I think it was a bit unclear, as what you suggested would return "Jokes", not the ID

Comment: Did you try it? In the code you provided, `joke` would point to a child object of "Jokes". If you're able to get the value "JokeText" then you're looking at an object whose key is the generated ID.

Comment: I appreciate your help, i have tried it but unfortunately it doesn't return the value of the id, it returns "Jokes". I have included the code that I am interested in, if you refer to the JSON structure it might make my question more clear